# Why doesn't site:.pdf work in Google?

Tags: google-search

I tried using `site:.pdf` for finding websites ending with .pdf but it did not showed up anything. If I would have googled "free pdf books" etc it shows up pdf results. Why doesn't it show up the my query?

Answer (score 12):

Because `site:` operator works for TLDs and `.pdf` is *not* a tld. It's a file type. use the `filetype:` operator to search for pdf files. E.g. -

> [origin of species filetype:pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=origin+of+species+filetype%3Apdf)

Results -

[image: Google results]

Comment: Filetype does not work for me.

Comment: `filetype`, not `Filetype`.

Comment: `google filetype:.html` shows up no results.

Comment: Read the answer carefully. see what you're doing wrong. yeah, your query is wrong.

Comment: this is the right answer. You can't include the `.` in the search query.